# Cant access a flask server listening on 0.0.0.0:5000 inside a docker that specifies "EXPOSE 5000"

Tags: docker

My dockerized `flask` server can't be reached from my host machine.

The server is running on `0.0.0.0:5000` and the Dockerfile specifies `EXPOSE 5000`, but I still can't reach it using `curl 127.0.0.1:5000/endpoint` [`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused`]

. When running the server on the host directly, I can reach it with the same `curl` command...

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY requirements.txt server.py ./

RUN apk add python3 && \
    apk add py3-pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
~
```

---

server.py

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=5000,
    )
```

Comment: Are you running your container using the `-p 5000:5000` flag?

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto My bad. I was under the impression that `EXPOSE` does the same as `-P`. Thanks!

Comment: Your container doesn't listen on your host's ports, so 127.0.0.1 may be the wrong address. Use `docker inspect` to find the address, map the port as above or use `--network host` to share the same network.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `--network host` is basically publishing all of the ports, no? Wouldn't it be an overkill? Why not use Gustavo's answer?

Comment: You see I don't ;P I just pointed out a thing I saw in TFM :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not binding the port 5000 when you're running your container instance. Keep in mind that `EXPOSE` does not bind automatically the ports when you run the container, it's just a hint of what should be exposed.